# VBNet Webforms Web Service as Ajax Intermediary

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, webforms

I am a PHP/Vue.js/jQuery developer who just started a new job where my first task is to clean up a Web Forms project written in Visual Basic in 2009.  I'm leading with that, so if this is a sounds clueless, it's because in many ways it is.

I'm looking to create a web service (or something) to serve as an interface between the web ui `aspx` files and project scoped VB classes in the background.  I'd like to have javascript ajax requests connect to lightweight intermediary methods in the `.asmx` file that will route the request to various classes that do the heavy lifting.  My thinking is that that way I can I can keep the backend logic separate from the front end logic in an easily manageable fashion, and they can receive calls either from the my web service or from a different vb class and respond accordingly.

My Questions are:

1. Is this a viable/sane way to go about things?  If not, can you tell me what is wrong with my thinking process?
2. If this is solid, then:

   1. Can I split the web service between multiple files
   2. Are there any *gotcha's* I should know about?

Edit:  Also - just because I believe this would be a better solution, and it's bound to get thought of:  I've been asked not to move this to an MVC/Web API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebForms have code-behind files for that inteface between the front-end and the project-scoped files, the thought was aspx for the UI, code-behind for the business layer which then made calls to either further business layers, or to the data layer.

Also, don't forget that for WebForms the standard behavior is to post a page back to itself on submission of form controls. Changing that behavior may make later modifications/maintenance harder as some parts will use your new handler/AJAX call  model, while others use the post-back paradigm, and code-behind pages.

Ultimately, there's nothing inherently wrong with what you're describing. It's still a viable paradigm, it's just not taking advantage of the benefits of WebForms, while you're still constrained by the drawbacks of them.

That said, I would probably not use ASMX files for what you're attempting. ASMX are '[WebServices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.services.webservice?view=netframework-4.7.2)' and they default to SOAP and "[WebMethods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.services.webmethodattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2)."

You would probably have a better experience if you used ASHX (Generic Handlers) for your AJAX calls. ASHX will return whatever you tell it to, and don't really have a 'default' behavior. As such, you can easily have them respond with JSON or XML.

Based on what you described as your prior experience my guess as to the biggest gotcha that will catch you, is that, by default, WebForms change the ID for server controls as it needs to, based on the control's parents.

So, if you have either of these:

```
<asp:textbox runat="server" id="txtFoo" />
<input type="text" runat="server" id="txtBar" />
```

These would not find DOM elements

```
$("#txtFoo").on("change", function() {alert('hi');});
$("#txtBar").on("change", function() {alert('hi');});
```

But these would

```
$("#<% Response.Write(txtFoo.ClientId)%>").on("change", function() {alert('hi');});
$("#<% Response.Write(txtBar.ClientId)%>").on("change", function() {alert('hi');});
```

And to just make it more confusing, if you had this:

```
<input type="text" id="txtFooBar" />
```

Then this WOULD find a DOM element

```
$("#txtFooBar").on("change", function() {alert('hi');});
```

The reason is that txtFooBar is not a server control, while txtFoo and txtBar are.

Comment: Thank you very much for this.  This makes me feel much better because it reveals to me that I'm not braindead, and that there are no - or at least none that jump out at you - serious 'gotchas' that I haven't considered.  I've decided to remove all the postback requests -  because one of my jobs was to speed up the interface and these seem to be the biggest performance hits.  Rather than using the webservice as an intermediary, would you say that using each code behind page as an intermediary would be "better"?

Comment: If the postbacks are being slow, I would assume there's something wrong there.  Unless I'm doing heavy database lifting, postbacks are fairly quick in my experience. Yes, they are slower than an AJAX call,  but that should solely be because you're moving more data down the pipe.  For example, if an AJAX API call takes 0.5 second, I would expect a similar postback call to take 2-3. Also be aware that ripping out all the postbacks, and replacing them with API/service calls, can be construed as replacing the webforms with a web api.

Comment: Thanks -  that helps!